# node.js setInterval not changing session variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I'm new to javascript and been struggling with function setInterval and sessions in node.js.

I have this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session')({
    secret: 'shhh_very_secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false
    }
});

app.use(session);

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {


    if (!req.session.visited) {
        console.log('First visit!');
        req.session.visited = true;
        req.session.state = 'default';

        setInterval(function() {
            req.session.state = "changed";
        }, 3000);

    } else {
        console.log('Page refreshed!');
        console.log('This should output "changed" but it does not');
        console.log(req.session.state);
    }
    res.send('Hi!');
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Can someone please explain to my whe the req.session.state is default after I refresh the page? Sessions are working well otherwise I wouldn't even get printed out what is inside else {}.

Answer (score 0):

1. The anonymous function you pass to `get()` runs.
2. It triggers the interval
3. You call `res.send()` and send the response
4. 3 seconds later the interval completes and you change the state

… by that time the request has already been finished with.

If you want to modify data in the session, do it before you finish dealing with a particular request.

Comment: But this is the purpose. To change the data after res.send(). But when I make another request after 10 seconds I should see already changed data. Or? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid but I still don't understand.

Comment: @Matumizuro I think the session state is persisted right away once the request is done, so you're changing an in memory copy of the session variable no one is interested in anymore.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson Oh, I see now. What can I do to change session data every X seconds not dependant on user's request?

Comment: Store a timestamp in the session. Calculate the value on demand based on that.

Comment: @Quentin I have no idea what you just said. What can I google in order to understand that?

Comment: @Matumizuro Say you're increasing a value by 1 every 3 seconds, if you're at 1 and save the time of the last request in the session and get a new request 28 seconds later, you can calculate that the number would have increased 9 times and return 10 without actually increasing all the time. Make sense? (when I actually got my math correct)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for clarification. But wouldn't that mean if I'm waiting too many seconds and then reload it will be a big amount of data transferred at once?

Comment: Nothing about this approach is any different from your original approach as regards to the frequency of the requests from the client.